# MySQL row ID appears to be array of numbers or encrypted

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, blob

I have been given a tech test to complete with a few MySQL tables. I was told to have MySQL Server 5+ on my machine which I believe I have.

Anyone know how I can make sure (I'm on a Mac)?

Stack

- Node.JS
- MySQL
- Express
- React

However when I ran the MySQL script to create all the tables all the IDs appear encrypted or just jumbled(see image 1). However when I access the table with the jumbled IDs via my API and return the data the IDs appear to be objects like the below.

Image 1
[image]

surveyId when returned from database.

```
surveyId: {
    data: [12, 215, 191, 155, 118, 8, 64, 184, 140, 252, 91, 117, 104, 89, 96, 213]
    type: 'Buffer
}
```

I'm supposed to be using these IDs in the tech test to access data in other tables(relationships), however in the database they are 'jumbled' and when returned from the database, seemingly unusable.

I've looked into converting them from a BLOB to a string or hex with no luck.

Does anyone know if I'm supposed to do some kind of conversion on the array to turn it into an ID?

No info on this was giving in the instructions, only that I would need to access the data in the database and transform it. I'm thinking the transform bit might be the conversion of these Ids.

Edit. MySQL info as requested:

```
INSERT: `CREATE TABLE `surveydata` (
  `surveyDataId` binary(16) NOT NULL,) PRIMARY KEY (`surveyDataId`) USING BTREE ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;`
```

```
INSERT INTO `surveydata` VALUES (0x000E36A69D55696D33271EA314932EF1, DEFAULT, 0xAD2ADA564B0911EXXXXX0A3056XXX36A, DEFAULT, 0, NULL, DEFAULT, '-', 'chrome', 0, '2016-08-07 20:08:13', NULL, 0xAE6AF02F4B091XXXXXXXA3056FD536A, DEFAULT, 0xAE6AF02F4B0XXXXXXXXX3056FD536A, DEFAULT, NULL, DEFAULT, NULL, DEFAULT, 216, 'EV', 'TR', 'VI', 'PE', b'0', 'en_GB', NULL, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Can you show some of the script that you ran to create the table and populate it? That might give a clue as to what is being stored in there. Are they "unusable" when you retrieve them from the database, or are they in the object form that you displayed? You seem to contradict yourself there. It looks as if there is some technique used to encode that object into the "stuff" that you see on the screen, and perhaps the creation script will show what it is.

Comment: Added some info as requested. I would say they are unusable when I retrieve them from the database as I can't use an array of strings as an Id to relate to another table. Yes they are in the object form I displayed when I get them from the DB via my API. Hope that helps.

Comment: Looking at it maybe BTREE has something to do with this?

Comment: Well, these are simply very big (128-bit) unsigned integers - so they are represented in hex format. I suppose MySQL does not have a built-in UUID data type - so that is why they are using BINARY(16).

Comment: I see, thanks IVO. Do you know of a good way to convert?

Comment: *To a string. Presumably that will then be my ID.